# Laravel posts types categories

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need an array with categories, each category has 4 posts: an array with two posts with type_1 and array with two posts with type_2. Without type_3.

The display should look like this (not using blade):

```
category name_1

    post type_1 name
    post type_1 name

    post type_2 name
    post type_2 name

category name_2

    post type_1 name
    post type_1 name

    post type_2 name
    post type_2 name
```

posts_table:

```
$table->enum('type', ['type_1', 'type_2', 'type_3'])->default('type_1');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

categories_table:

```
$table->string('name');
```

Category model:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
```

Post model:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
```

I tried:

```
$categories = ['category_1', 'category_2'];

foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $postsType1[$cat->name] = $cat->posts()->where('type', 'type_1')->latest()->limit(2)->get();
    $postsType2[$cat->name] = $cat->posts()->where('type', 'type_2')->latest()->limit(2)->get();
}
```

But these are two separate arrays in categories. I need one categories array with 2 posts of each type.

Comment: does your posts table have a column called `category_id` and if so, is that column set to a valid category_id for each entry?

Comment: Yes, it does. I forgot to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the collection `groupBy()` with multiple conditions

```php
$posts = Post::query()
    ->latest()
    ->get()
    ->groupBy([
        function($post) {
            return $post->category->name;
        },
        function($post) {
            return $post->type;
        },
    ])
    ->map(function($records, $category) {
      return $records->sortKeys()->map(function($rows, $type){
          return $rows->take(2)->all();
      });
    })
    ->all();
```

And if you want to just group by the Category name and sort by Post type

```php
$posts = Post::get()
    ->group(function($post){
        return $post->category->name;
    })
    -> map(function($value, $key){
        return $value->sortBy('type')->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(2);
    })
    ->all();
```

**UPDATE**
To avoid fetching all Post records without any limit another option would be to:

- create a composite index on the posts table for better query performance

```php
//in migration file for the posts table
$table->index(['type', 'category_id']);
```

- define 3 relationships on the Category model

```php
class Category extends Model
{

    public function type1News()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('type', 'type_1')->latest();
    }

    public function type2News()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('type', 'type_2')->latest();
    }

    public function type3News()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('type', 'type_3')->latest();
    }
}
```

Then to get the data

```php
 $categories = Cache::remember('categoriesWithLatestNews', 3600, function() {
    $cats = Category::get();

    $cats->each->load([
        'type1News' => function($query){
            return $query->take(2);
        },
        'type2News' => function($query){
            return $query->take(2);
        },
        'type3News' => function($query){
            return $query->take(2);
        }
    ]);

    return $cats;
});
```

With 1 million records in the posts table the response time was 2.75 seconds for the first time. (Without composite index the response time is over 120s)

Then after it is cached for the specified seconds so response time is in ms.

Though this approach requires multiple database queries a total of 31 (10 category records) queries: 1 to get all categories and then 3 for each categories to get the relations.

Comment: How should i limit / latest by type in categories?

Comment: Don't get it - do you mean to say that you want to sort by created date in descending order and then sort by type in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, i want to ->latest()->limit(2) for each type

Comment: @BraddyPhil Have updated the answer to first sort by `type` then by `latest` and limit the records as per your previous comment - check & let me know if that gives the desired output for you

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Let's say I have 1000 news (iteration of all news using the all() and get() (without limiting) methods are not suitable) and 10 categories. Let's say I need 4 news per category, divided, for example, into two types - important (2 news) and not so (2 news).

Comment: @BraddyPhil Have updated answer with another option